# Cost-efficient ingestion for results of DLP job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I'm running a DLP jo on BigQuery tables and need the results (including PII location) to be stored somewhere. As I see in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/concepts-actions?_ga=2.267497997.-2093094899.1613137171#available_actions) I can put the results to BigQuery but DLP uses [streaming inserts which add more costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data_ingestion_pricing). Meanwhile Batch loading to BQ is free. PubSub and Cloud Monitoring is even more expensive.

Are there any cheap options to store DLP results?

Comment: The best solution is to store data to BigQuery. I didn't find the reference that mention the streaming write and the additional cost. In any case, this cost is about 5% of your DLP cost; $1/Gb for DLP, $0.05/Gb for BigQuery streaming insert. Ok, money worth, but, it's very few compare to DLP

Comment: Each of the GCP services have various attributes by which their pricing is calculated, to get an estimation of the price per month, you can use the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). Did you try this?